# Deferred javascript noConflict different version jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, deferred-loading

In my one function I need use **twice** jquery version. One for **all** function and another  jquery for **one** function..

I can not control conflict in deffering.

> ```
> <script defer type='text/javascript' src='<%=FrSettings.Settings.AppVirtualPath %>resource/js/jquery-11.0.min.js'></script>
> <script defer type='text/javascript' src='<%=FrSettings.Settings.AppVirtualPath %>resource/js/unitegallery.min.js'></script>
> <script defer type='text/javascript' src='<%=FrSettings.Settings.AppVirtualPath %>resource/js/ug-theme-carousel.js'></script>
> <script defer type='text/javascript' src='<%=FrSettings.Settings.AppVirtualPath %>resource/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
> ```

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        (function ($) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            // Need 2 different jquery version
            LoadVideos();
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });


       // Need only 1 jquery version
       window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        (function ($) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                LoadAnaOwl();
                LoadYayinAkisi();
                $('body').on('click', '.mansetPaginition li a', function () {
                    $('.mansetPaginition li a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
                $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.mansetPaginition li a', function () {
                    $('.mansetPaginition li a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    window.location.hash = this.hash;
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

`jQuery.noConflict(bool)` will return the jQuery function and restores the $ global variable to its old reference. `bool` indicates whether or not to remove all global jQuery variables, including jQuery. Calling `jQuery.noConflict(true)` if there are two versions of jQuery loaded will restore the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        (function ($) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            window.jq331 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            // Need 2 different jquery version
            LoadVideos();
            });
        })(jQuery);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jq331 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
//jQuery and $ is version 1.1.0
//jq331 is version 3.3.1
console.log('jQuery version:',jQuery.fn.jquery);
console.log('$ version:', $.fn.jquery);
console.log('jq331 version:',jq331.fn.jquery);
</script>
```

Comment: For one query version is jq110 okey but for another ? I need 2 jquery version in LoadVideos

Comment: @AlicanKablan You shouldn't have 2 different versions of jQuery. Fix this issue first. Don't reply with "but I need it", find a way to fix it.

Comment: @hev1 Thank you my friend this is answer for me.

Comment: @AlicanKablan No problem.